# Is there any way to handle "Array response" return from API call

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm testing a API where it return response as a Array,I am finding it difficult in storing in list or Array?

I am using JsonPath to fetch the records

API response looks  like this

```
[
    "String1",
    "String2",
    "String3",
    "String4",
    "String5"
]
```

I am Using below code

```
Response response;
JsonPath jsonPathEvaluator = response.jsonPath();
jsonPathEvaluator.getString("[0]");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try following to get list of strings:

```
List<String> = jsonPathEvaluator.get();
```

or

```
List<String> = jsonPathEvaluator.getList("");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSONArrayRequest() method which works similar to JSONObjectRequest().

If it's for a GET request method, here is how the sample code will look like:

```
JsonArrayRequest requestData = JSONArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, 'https://your-api/endpoint', null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>(){
   
  @Override
  public void onResponse(JSONArray response){

     //do whatever you want with the response data from here

  }      


 }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
    
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
      //whenever there is an error in response...
     // ...the code works, data is usually retrieved, just that it's not the 
     //... intended type
    }

  });

// add the request to the queue
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
requestQueue.add(requestData);
```

Don't forget to import the required classes.

Answer (score -1):

It is better if you have tags for you element lists if they are of one type:-

```
{  
   "Strings":[  
      "String1",
      "String2",
      "String3",
      "String4",
      "String5"
   ]
}

JsonArray arrObj = empObj.getJsonArray("Strings");
```

This will return you a JsonArray that you can convert to any type based on your requirement

If you cannot change the input json , maybe this could help :-

```
 String [] json = new  String[10];
 obj = parser.parse(response);
 String jsoString = obj.toString();
 List<String> items = Arrays.asList(jsoString.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```